# Where does the EMF Client Platform store local files?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-emf, emf

According to [this acrticle](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/getting-started-with-the-emf-client-platform/#components) , the EMF Client Platform demo application stores the objects you create either in an EMFstore or in local files. As I do not have an EMFstore, I thought the application would store the information in .xmi files or something like that. Whenever I close the application and relaunch it, my created projects and objects are loaded correctly. But I can't find any files in my workspace! And I am sure that I'm looking inside the correct workspace because I use the `-data` flag to launcht the application and the .metadata folder was created successfully. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know this app but usually when you launch an app from Eclipse it creates a new workspace for the app. The 'Run > Run Configuration' for the app shows you where this is in the 'Location' field.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but my created objects are stored in a folder named runtime-EclipseApplication side by side with the workspace folder. I assume your "created objects" is referring to the modelInstances like "TournamentPro" or "League" in the given example article. If you do not have these folders, you should check again if you really do not have an EMFstore.